# How To Seed Data Files Using Sequelize and Custom Function With Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to use Sequelize in NodeJS and am using their Seeders CLI to try and add a query to bulkInsert command. I have created a simple JS function and everytime I run the sequelize migration command it returns a null value error. I also tried to do a beforeCreate method, but I'm not sure why the errors says that function does not exist. Here is what I need help with in code.

passGen.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js

function BpassGen(password){
    bcrypt.hash(password, 15, function(err, hash) {
        return hash;
      });
}

exports.BpassGen = BpassGen;
```

Then my Seed File

```
'use strict';
const PassGenX = require('../helpers/passwordGeneration');
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
const uuidV1 = require('uuid/v1');
const Accounts = require('../models/accounts');

const uuidT = uuidV1();

var password = PassGenX.BpassGen('secretConfig');

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

   // ERROR: Accounts.beforeCreate is not a function
   Accounts.beforeCreate((Accounts, options) => {
      return PassGenX.BpassGen('secretConfig').then(hashedPw => {
        Accounts.password = hashedPw;
      });
    });

   return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Accounts', [
    {
      uid: uuidT,
      userName: 'NaniMae1',
      firstName: 'Nani',
      lastName: 'Mae',
      dateOfBirth: new Date(),
      email: 'yaya@gmail.com',
      backupEmail: 'dsf@gmail.com',
      phoneNumber: null,
      phoneNumberStatus: 1,
      twoFactorEnabled: 1,
      imageURL: null,
      passwordHash: '',
      passwordKey: '',
      securityStamp: '',
      userLimit: 10,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      Id_dataValidity: 1,
      Id_status: 1,
      Id_accountRole: 1,
      Id_inviteKey: 1,
      Id_privacy: 2
    }
], {});
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

  }
};
```

I also tried adding the password field to call the function, but it still results into null:

```
password: PassGenX.BpassGen('secretKey'),
```

What I want to do is maybe I need to add a promise? How would I do that? 
What I thought would happen is that my helper function would get called and then the password field will have the bcrypt hash, but that did not happen. In the CLI I just get the same error of 'password does not accept a null value' because in my models (sequelize migration definition) field for null is false, so it cannot be null.

How can I use my helper function to generate a password that is used in my seeder file for creating an account in Sequelize?

EDIT:
How can I implement hooks like this such as direct method into my Account model js AND Account migration js files? [sequelize hook docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html)

Or what about adding another QueryInterface like Upsert?

[Upsert Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-upsert)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are requiring the file itself, without sequelize.

Could you please try to change this line:

```
const Accounts = require('../models/accounts');
```

to:

```
const model = require('../models/index');
```

And then use it as:

```
model.Accounts.beforeCreate{(...
```

Comment: Hi, if I provide the field for password in my bulkInsert method, do I leave it blank? I applied your suggestion and get:

ERROR: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Could you check my post again, I added an edit with some new suggestions.